# Normal subgroup, and cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

problem: For a subgroup $N$ of a group $G$, prove if $N$ is normal, then each left coset of $N$ is also a right coset, that is for all $a \in G$, there exists a $b \in G$, such that  $aN = Nb$.

Attempt: Suppose $N$ is a normal subgroup. Then we know $N = aNa^{-1}$, for all $a \in G$. Suppose $ana^{-1}$ is an element in  $N$, then there exists a $b \in N$ such that $b = ana^{-1}$.  So multiply both sides of $b = ana^{-1}$ by $a$, to get $ba = an$. Then if $c$ is an element in $N$, then $ba = an$ implies $(ba)c = (an)c = a(nc)$. So $a(nc)$ is in $N$. Since both $n$ and $c$ are also in $N$.

Similarly $N = bnb^{-1}$. Suppose $bnb^{-1}$ is an element in $N$, then there exists an $a$ such that $a = bnb^{-1}$. Thus $ab = bn$. So if $c$ is an element in $N$, then $ab = bn$ implies $c(bn) = c(ab) = (ca)b$ which is an element of $Nb$. So $aN \subset Nb$ and $Nb \subset aN$. Thus $aN = Nb$.

Can someone please check if this does make sense? And please any help/feedback/hints, would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: First line: Careful.  We know only that, for some $a \in G$, $aNa^{-1} \subset N$.

Comment: @Kaj_H:  if $N$ if normal in $G$, then $aNa^{-1} = N$ for *all* $a \in G$, if I am not mistaken.  That is the *definition* of normal subgroup.

Comment: @RobertLewis:  You're right.  Oops.

Comment: @Kaj_H:  these definitions get so confusing, especially when one is learning them, and there are so many of them, it is easy to make mistakes.  After my algebra final I got them so mixed up it took me years to unravel this stuff! ;-)!  Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm having a hard time following the argument presented in the text of the question, and I don't think it is completely correct.  For example, since $nc \in N$, if $a \in G - N$ (that is, $a \in G$, $a \notin N$), then $a(nc) \notin N$.  If it were, say $a(nc) = m \in N$, then $a = m(nc)^{-1} \in N$, a contradiction.  In fact, $a(nc) \in aN$, a left coset of $N$, and $N \cap aN = \varnothing$ since left cosets are either disjoint or identical, as are right cosets.

The easiest way I know to show that left cosets are right cosets (and *vice versa*!) for normal $N$ is to use $aNa^{-1} = N$; then $aN = Na$ so the left and right cosets represented by $a$ (that is, containing $a$) are identical.  It's as simple as that.

Hope this helps.  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Comment: I understand it that way, but that b in the problem is getting me confuse.

Comment: @user65903:  if the problem is to show that $b$ *exists*, just take $b = a$ for *any* $a \in G$!

Comment: Thank you, then I will do that.

Comment: @user65903:  (continuation of previous comment)  This *exhibits* a $b$ with the desired property $aG = Gb (= Ga!)$; you don't need to manipulate $b$ other than this!